# Take an input from a user and call a attribute of a class from it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a text based game where i need to convert a input from a user into a number which is an attribute to the class, I have 2 different scripts one which stores all the "abilities" and one which does the actual "fighting"

Script 1

```
> #Abilities
import Nstats

class Ability():
        def __init__(self,AP,Desc):
                self.AP=int(AP)
                self.Desc=Desc
SHP=Ability(10,"Super Hard Punch!")
SWP=Ability(32,"Literally kills you!!")
```

Script 2

>

```
 def convert(inp):
    cmnd2 = {'SHP':Abilities.SHP}
    cmnd2[inp]
    for inp in [Abilities.SHP,Abilities.SWP]:
        inp = inp.AP

def Battle():
    while Nstats.NHealth >= 0:
        roll = randint(0,50)
        print("Your Avaialbe Ability's are:", Nstats.NAbilities,)
        inp = input("What would you like to use?")
        if inp in Nstats.NAbilities:
            convert(inp)
            print(inp)
Battle()
```

I am trying to somehow convert the Input into the value to then use in an algorithm to work out "damage" done however I am not sure how to achieve this.

to avoid confusion NStats is a simple document with this code

```
> Nlevel = 1
NHealth = 500
NMP = 500
NAbilities = ['SHP']
Ninventory = []
```

this is what I used previosly but couldn't get a desired outcome

> 

```
inp = input("What would you like to use?")
        cmnd = {'SHP':Abilities.SHP.AP,'SWP':Abilities.SWP}
        if inp in Nstats.NAbilities:
            cmnd[inp]
            damage = int((inp*2)) + (roll*2)
```

Comment: What is `Nstats.NAbilities`? Is it a list? A dictionary? Tuple? Class?

Comment: where are you getting the value from?

Comment: Nstats.NHealth is just another .py file called Nstats where attributes such as NHealth are defined, NAbilities is a list

Comment: okie.... but what about my question about `NAbilities`?

Comment: Put your Abilities in a dict, keyed on their names. Then when you get the string the player inputs, you can just look if its in the dict and retrieve the Ability. The other alternative is just a chain of if/elif. So `if inp == Super Hard Punch: return Abilities.SHP`. I wouldn't go with the kind of class introspection, it's a terrible code smell.

Comment: @Paul Rooney Thats what I did initially however whenever I retrieved the ability I couldn't retrieve its "AP" attribute which was needed for the next line of code where that value is put into an Algorithm to work out damage. I thought about using a chain of If's however that was impractical as in it would be repeating code a lot

Comment: Your convert function certainly looks suspect. It defines the dict, but doesnt capture the result of `cmnd2[inp]`. Maybe `ability = cmnd2[inp]`? (although take care for exception if the value is not present). I'm also unsure about the purpose of the loop (your loop variable overwrites the input argument). Finally the function doesnt return anything or alter any global state, so why have it at all?

Comment: I cant get to seem the formatting right on this so I would appreaciate if anyone could edit this nonetheless here is the snippet of code I used previosly but couldn't get to work

`inp = input("What would you like to use?")
cmnd = {'SHP':Abilities.SHP.AP,'SWP':Abilities.SWP 
if inp in Nstats.NAbilities:
cmnd[inp]
damage = int((inp*2)) + (roll*2)`

Comment: Yes the convert function I made was at the end of my wits I which is why I came here for help, It defininantly is a very horrible piece of code but If I could just get the methodology to do this I would tidy it up.

Comment: `if inp in cmnd: damage = cmnd[inp].AP`. Now you have the damage value in a variable.

Comment: Thank you a ton this was a life saver @Paul Rooney

Answer (score 0):

Based on your title, I am assuming you are trying to get or set attributes programatically. You can use `setattr(object, attr, value)` and `getattr(object, attr)` to get and set attributes programatically:

```
>>> help(setattr)
setattr(obj, name, value, /)
    Sets the named attribute on the given object to the specified value.

    setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to ``x.y = v''

>>> help(getattr):
getattr(...)
    getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value

    Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.
    When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't
    exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will read about this and try it and get back if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a starting / Lookup point:

```
import random

class Ability():
    """Holds data of attacks:
    ap = cost, desc= description, damage = ap + randint(0,ap), key = key to use it"""
    def __init__(self,ap,desc,key):
        self.ap = int(ap)
        self.desc = desc  
        self.key = key

    def __str__(self, **kwargs):
        """Print one ability."""
        return f'  {self.key} -> {self.desc} for {self.ap} AP'


class NStats :
    """Stats of player/monster"""
    def __init__(self, health:int, actionpoints:int):
         self.health = health
         self.ap = actionpoints
         self.abilities  = { "SHP"  :Ability( 5,"Super Hard Punch", "SHP" ), 
                             "WP"   :Ability( 1,"Weak Punch", "WP" ), 
                             "KAME" :Ability(50,"All Out Attack", "KAME" ), 
                             "SA"   :Ability(10,"Your Special Attack", "SA" ) } 
    def printAbs(self): 
        """Print own abilities"""
        for n in sorted(self.abilities, key = lambda x: self.abilities[x].ap):
            print(str(self.abilities[n]))

    def attack(self, other):
        """Attack other. TODO: other should retaliate. Currently you
        die only by exausting all your ap."""
        print("FIIIIIGHT")
        while other.health > 0 and self.health > 0:
            print(f'Rest Health: {self.health} Rest AP: {self.ap}  vs  {other.health}')
            self.printAbs()
            what = input("What to do...\n" ).upper()

            # dict.get(key,default) - if key not in dict, it returns None 
            ab = self.abilities.get(what,None)
            # only if attack found in dict AND ap are enough
            if ab and ab.ap <= self.ap:
                other.health -= ab.ap + random.randint(0,ab.ap) # damage of attack
                self.ap -= ab.ap    # cost of attack

            # only if attack found in dict AND ap too low
            elif ab and ab.ap > self.ap:
                print("you are too exhausted and loose another 10 AP")
                self.ap -= 10 

            # no else : typos simply query for new input 

            if other.health <= 0:
                print("You win")
                break
            elif self.health <= 0 or self.ap <= 0:
                print("You loose")
                break

# lets fight, me vs you ;o)
Me = NStats(100,100)
You = NStats(100,5)

Me.attack(You)
```

Output:

```
 FIIIIIGHT
Rest Health: 100 Rest AP: 100  vs  100
  WP -> Weak Punch for 1 AP
  SHP -> Super Hard Punch for 5 AP
  SA -> Your Special Attack for 10 AP
  KAME -> All Out Attack for 50 AP
What to do...
shp
Rest Health: 100 Rest AP: 95  vs  93
  WP -> Weak Punch for 1 AP
  SHP -> Super Hard Punch for 5 AP
  SA -> Your Special Attack for 10 AP
  KAME -> All Out Attack for 50 AP
What to do...
kame
Rest Health: 100 Rest AP: 45  vs  15
  WP -> Weak Punch for 1 AP
  SHP -> Super Hard Punch for 5 AP
  SA -> Your Special Attack for 10 AP
  KAME -> All Out Attack for 50 AP
What to do...
kame
you are too exhausted  and loose another 10 AP
Rest Health: 100 Rest AP: 35  vs  15
  WP -> Weak Punch for 1 AP
  SHP -> Super Hard Punch for 5 AP
  SA -> Your Special Attack for 10 AP
  KAME -> All Out Attack for 50 AP
What to do...
sa
Rest Health: 100 Rest AP: 25  vs  2
  WP -> Weak Punch for 1 AP
  SHP -> Super Hard Punch for 5 AP
  SA -> Your Special Attack for 10 AP
  KAME -> All Out Attack for 50 AP
What to do...
sa
You win
```

You win if you kill, you loose if your AP are 0 or lower